# How to set a relation cardinality of one to one in mysql?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

i need help with this one to one relation that i need to do in my mysql database.
I try to find the answer in the stackoverflow questions but i cant find it.
I have a table contact and a table address, the table contact has 4 address id's so this id's must be 4 foreign keys to the address table and in the address table, i need to have a contact foreign key. I'ts this correct? This would give me a (contact)1:*(address) relation?

How can i make this relation?

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct in regards on how you plan to set up your tables. That will give you a 1:* rel; however, your question title is misleading because you are asking how to set a "cardinality of one to one" and this is not a 1:1 rel.

Comment: I know.. the one to one is what i want because i want to know that one user has one address in each id_address that is in the contact table (are four of those id's)

Comment: You have your concepts mixed up. That is still a one to many rel. If you want to achieve what you want without the Bridge table Joe's proposing, simply add a contact_id column to the address table. But I insist, that is a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship here. You need to resolve this by introducing a new bridge table, `ContactAddressXref`, that contains foreign keys to both the Contact and Address tables.

Comment: No. Those address IDs go in the new bridge table. There should be no columns in the Contact table that reference Address.

Comment: Yes, but in that bridge table, i cannot know that a contact has only 4 address (no less, no more).

Comment: @Phoenix_uy why do you want "4 address (no less, no more)"? That's kind of an odd requirement.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy: I'd suggest that you enforce a rule like that with middle-tier business logic rather than in database design.